# Why in android If/Else statement always else is activating

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I want save timestamp in timestamp variable, but always else active and the value of timestamp variable change.

```
    String timestamp = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_product);

    if (!timestamp.equals("")) {

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        timestamp= preferences.getString("timestamp", "");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), timestamp + "iffff", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        String ts = tsLong.toString();

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("timestamp", ts);
        editor.commit();
        timestamp = preferences.getString("timestamp", "");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), timestamp + "elseee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `timestamp`  is declared in the class, which get destroyed and recreated by android before `onCreate`  is called. So when you get to the `onCreate`  `timestamp` is always empty. You should put the code to retrieve the `timestamp` outside the `if` and then do your tests like this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_product);

    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    timestamp= preferences.getString("timestamp", "");

    if (!timestamp.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), timestamp + "iffff", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        String ts = tsLong.toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("timestamp", ts);
        editor.commit();
        timestamp = preferences.getString("timestamp", "");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), timestamp + "elseee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`String timestamp = "";` This statement initializes timestamp to "" so timestamp is always == "" Hence else part will  be executed. Remember this function executes once in this class. So it always executes after the iniallization

Comment: In else statement i definition timestamp, so just in first should go to else part. how can to define timestamp that works true.

Comment: Yes i see that. But onCreate only executes once when you are creating that activity